# I am a person, but my identity is unknown. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

*I am a person, but my identity is unknown.  Who am I?*

---

> **I am interested in an object that was first created in 1936.**
>
> **I am known across the web.**
>
> **I am unknown to people who try and track me down.**
>
> **I smile when you look at me.**
>
> **I cause protesting, trouble and more things.**

---

*Who am I?*

---

*By Kane Chauhan.*

---

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This sounds like trivia instead of a riddle - pure trivia is off-topic here. Also, the computer-puzzle tag is for puzzles that require computers, usually for file manipulation. Please check the tag wikis before you use them.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably a

> Turing machine.

Hence the computer tag.

I am interested in an object that was first created in 1936

> You were created in 1936.

I am known across the web

> Also true.

I am unknown to people who try and track me down

> An actual, pure Turing machine doesn't exist.

I smile when you look at me

> In many pictures you'll see the tape configuration would look like a smile.

I cause protesting, trouble and more thing's

> At turing test competitions, there can be conflict because of different interpretations among other problems. For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loebner_Prize#Critisms

For the puzzle title, it makes sense because

> The inventor, Alan Turing is the person after which you are named, but yet you don't truly exist.

Answer (score 5):

I think of

> Anonymous

I am interested in an object that was first created in 1936.

> the computer. The first one (Z1 by Konrad Zuse) was created in 1936.

I smile when you look at me.

> Reference to the mask that represents them

The rest seems obvious to me.